# Swift: why mutating function can not be static

Tags: swift, operators, value-type

I have a theoretical question, I did not find related topics.

At some point, I decided that it would be nice to have a small extension for an array:

```
var array = [Int]()
array += 1
```

The code is quite simple:

```
extension Array {
    mutating static func +=(lhs: Array, rhs: Element) {
        lhs.append(rhs)
    }
}
```

To achieve this we align with two factors that make perfect sense to me:

- Array is a struct and this operation requires a mutation
- Infix operator reload requires a static function

Unfortunately, it is impossible due Swift does not allow mutating functions to be static. And this is the part I don't quite understand.

Comment: I would suggest against having such an extension. The standard library intentionally doesn't define a `+=` operator for appending single elements to an array, because it leads to ambiguous behaviour when attempting to add an array as an element to an array of arrays.

Comment: @Alexander: Independent of whether this is a good idea or not: I do not yet see the possible ambiguity. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR Surprisingly, Swift's overload resolution rules don't make it technically ambiguous, but for readers, it's quite unclear what this code would do: `var anyArray: [Any] = [0, 123.4, "foo", false];  anyArray += [1, 2, 3]` Will `anyArray` be `[0, 123.4, "foo", false, [1, 2, 3]]` or `[0, 123.4, "foo", false, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, with an array of Any it becomes ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mutating` doesn't mean "mutates anything", but rather, "mutates `self`". Your function attempts to mutate `lhs`, not `self`.

Your current code won't work because `lhs` is being passed by value. The `lhs` parameter is a local copy of whatever argument the caller supplied to it, thus any changes your function makes will be local to the function and won't persist. You'll need to instead have `lhs` be passed by reference, by delcaring it as a `inout Array`.

Comment: There *is* a `self` in a static method (the type itself). Of course that is not mutable.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, TIL.

Comment: More nitpicking: `inout` is not (necessarily) "passing by reference" :)

Comment: @MartinR is right here: "An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value."

Comment: @MartinR `inout` is currently (AFAIK always) compiled as a pass-by-reference, but still has the semantics of copy-in copy-out. The standard library simply wouldn't be able to make the time complexity guarantees that it does without the guarantee of `inout` being a pass-by-reference, e.g `append(_:)` being amortised O(1) (it's a `mutating` method, so the implicit `self` param is `inout`). If the implicit `self` param was copy-in copy-out, that'd be O(n), as it'd trigger a copy of the array's buffer.

Comment: @Hamish: Yes, thanks. I was more thinking of the official documentation which somewhere states that "as an optimization" the value can be passed by reference, and that one should not rely on it.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I know the bit you're referring to – I believe it's either outdated, or the Swift team decided to leave it as-is to reflect that the `inout` has the semantics of copy-in copy-out (and you shouldn't use the arg as a pointer!). Previously, you could capture `inout` args in escaping closures, so the function needed to make a shadow copy of the arg for the closure to capture – that's no longer the case tho. [The SIL docs](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#inout-arguments) are pretty clear that `inout` gets lowered as `@inout`, and that's a pass-by-ref though.

Answer (score 3):

Your `+=` mutates the first argument, not the `Array` type.
Therefore it must not be declared mutating (which makes no
sense for a static method because you cannot mutate the type), but the first parameter must be `inout`:

```
extension Array {
    static func +=(lhs: inout Array, rhs: Element) {
        lhs.append(rhs)
    }
}

var array = [Int]()
array += 1
print(array) // [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using static keyword before method name means, we call method by struct/class name (Not by an object) so we don't have any object here.
By using mutating keyword, we are mutating 'self' object. 
So while using static we don't have any object to mutate.